# regex for validation of wind format

Tags: regex, swift2

I am trying to validate a wind direction and speed format from Air Traffic Control e.g 190/10. wind direction must be from 001 to 360 and wind speed from 00 to 30.

I have tried

```
^(0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|30[0-9]|31[0-9]|32[0-9]|33[0-9]|34[0-9]|35[0-9]|36[0])[\/](0[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0])$
```

But it does not work. however this one works partly

```
^(0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|30[0-9]|31[0-9]|32[0-9]|33[0-9]|34[0-9]|35[0-9]|36[0])|/|(0[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0])$
```

Any help will be appreciated thks

Comment: Please take a moment to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think your question is about using '\' in your programming language that has not been tagged ;).

Comment: I hope this helps [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uY3xL4/1)

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM Great, I couldn't imagined that. (I would do regex `(\d{3})\/(\d{2})` and value evaluation (for $1 and $2) combination.)

Comment: If you are doing this in Swift, why are you trying to validate 0-360 in a regex? Just do that in Swift.

Comment: @dawg the textfield format input must be xxx/xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
^(?:[0-2]\d\d|3[0-5]\d|360)\/(?:[0-2]\d|30)$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/uY3xL4/3)

where,

(?: ... ) [Non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

- 1st Alternative: [0-2][0-9][0-9]
- 2nd Alternative: 3[0-5][0-9]
- 3rd Alternative: 360

`\/` matches the character `/` literally

(?: ... ) [Non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

- 1st Alternative: [0-2][0-9]
- 2nd Alternative: 30

Note: `\d` match a digit [0-9]

Comment: This works as I want in demo, but in swift 2 gives " invalid escape sequence in literal". Any ideas ?

Comment: beats me, edit your question add tag "swift" or you can do new question

Comment: Tried following in swift, no joy  ^(?|[0-2]\\d\\d|3[0-5]\\d|360)\\/(?|[0-2]\\d|30)$

Comment: you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\\d`.... and `/` instead of `\\/` .... I don't know about swift2 :(

Comment: Swift does not support branch reset groups (and they're really not needed here). Use a non-capturing group instead. Also, you need to escape backslashes twice:  `^(?:[0-2]\\d\\d|3[0-5]\\d|360)/(?:[0-2]\\d|30)$`

Answer (score 0):

For the `0-360` part, you can use:

```
'^((?:\d)|(?:\d\d)|(?:[0-3][0-5]\d)|(?:00\d)|(?:360))' # correctly anchored at the end
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK1jE4/1)

So, this is worth a go:

```
^((?:(?:\d)|(?:\d\d)|(?:[0-2]\d\d)|(?:3[0-5]\d)|(?:00\d)|(?:360))\/(?:(?:30)|(?:[0-2]\d)))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK1jE4/2)

Answer (score 0):

For swift 2 following changes required:

```
^(?:|[0-2]\\d\\d|3[0-5]\\d|360)\\/(?:|[0-2]\\d|30)$
```